# conditional URL re-writes using IIS 7.5

Tags: sharepoint, iis, url-rewriting

We have a bilingual SharePoint website and would like to ensure that all French content is funnelled through our french domain, lets just call it _frenchdomain.com.

Languages variations in SharePoint are separated by folder structure, so in our case you can go to _http://englishdomain.com/en for English content and _http://englishdomain.com/fr for French content.

My question is how can I get IIS to recognize **any** instance of _http://englishdomain.com/fr/* and instead rewrite it as _http://frenchdomain.com/fr/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <rule name="fr">
      <match url="fr/.*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^frenchdomain.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://frenchdomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
```